# SQL SSRS Mapping Results to a Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a number of profiles which have a certain level of permissions which are enumerated and stored within SQL.  I want to create within SSRS a report which shows all the permissions on the left side of the table and all the profiles on the top with an X or some indication of the profiles that have the appropriate permissions.  This information is stored across three tables.

Table 1: Profiles - Gives the names of the profiles related back to a GUID

Table 2: Profile_Priv - Gives the GUID of a profile with the permission number (only permissions actually granted to a profile appear in this table)

Table 3: Privileges - Relates the permission number back to the name of the permission.

I have a query that will pull the permissions assigned to a profile, and I can easily populate the blank matrix with all the possible permissions, but marrying the two is escaping me.  This is what I have in SSRS so far.  I am passing a parameter within SSRS called ProfileName to allow the query to show what ever profiles are needed for that particular report.

```
Select Privileges.Description, Profiles.Name
FROM Privileges LEFT OUTER JOIN
Profile_Priv ON Privileges.ID = Profile_Priv.ID INNER JOIN
Profiles ON Profile_Priv.PID = Profiles.PID
WHERE (Profiles.Name = @ProfileName)
ORDER BY Privileges.ID
```

This doesn't populate any of the information in the table like I expected it to, and also will not do any type of data transform like turning the value to Yes.

Any feedback or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Addition 1:

Even when changing it to a Full Join, doing an individual Profile only returns the Permissions that the specific Profile has.

What I am looking to create is something like this in a report:

```
               Profile 1     Profile 2     Profile 3    Profile 4
Permission 1   X                           X                     
Permission 2   X             X             X            X
Permission 3                 X                          X
Permission 4
```

Currently I get this using the example from above if I was searching for Profile 2:

```
               Profile 2                              
Permission 2   X             
Permission 3   X
```

Comment: You need to add examples of the data you are currently getting, and the way you want it to look on the report.

Comment: Added additional information for clarification purposes.

Comment: You're filtering for **Profile 2** so Permissions **2** and **3** are the only ones expected. You should remove your WHERE clause if you want them all in the Matrix otherwise your filter will only allow the selected Profile in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a full outer join, but instead of using a WHERE clause, use a CASE Statement to return something like either "True" (if the Profile has that Permission) or "False" if it doesn't.  That way you always get all permissions.

Comment: The case statement solved the issue perfectly.  Thank you.